# Why do I get different version of a dependency in package-lock.json?

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

I'm working on an `angular 10` app. Why do I see a version of a dependency in `package-lock.json` that is different than what I've put in `package.json` + cmd :`npm install`

example :

- package.json

  "dependencies": {
  "underscore": "**^1.12.0**",
  ....
  }
- then I lunch `npm install`
- Package-lock

  "underscore": {
  "version": "**1.13.1**",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.13.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-..."
  },

Why in package.json it's version 1.12.0 and in the other json it's 1.13.1 ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the full [semver](https://semver.org/) documentation for more details, but when you write `^1.12.0`, you're effectively writing a version *range*, not a single version.

Short reference:

- `^1.12.0` => latest version that is `1.x.x`
- `~1.12.0` => latest version that is `1.12.x`
- `1.12.0` => exactly `1.12.0`

According to the semver `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH` convention, any version with the same `MAJOR` number doesn't contain breaking changes, so you'll usually see package versions specified with the `^` range; you get the latest updates *and* your code doesn't break!

However, unlike `package.json`, `package-lock.json` always contains the exact versions of packages installed to...well...lock them. That's why your `package-lock.json` can show a higher version than what you specified in `package.json`.

Of course, if for any reason this isn't ok and you need to stick at a more specific version, you can use one of the other selectors.